# Display Absolute positioned element

Tags: css

I have a Relative positioned `span` inside a **ul** with `overflow-y: auto;`. I have another `span` with `absolute` position inside previous `span`.  I made a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/abufoysal/7q2a6hju/5/) in this regard.

How can I display `.tooltiptext` out of the `ul` ?

Answer (score 1):

```
First of all, please format the code before uploading it to 
other sources, so that we can help you resolve your issue.
As you have applied the Unordered list within the span, you are 
forcing it into a particular block, you can have the 
tooltiptext outside the unordered list by giving it a margin or 
you can try this approach
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yashrajjain726/h9jcawLp/)

Comment: wth is that text formatting though

Comment: text formatting is formatting the code one under one in a particularly structured way, such that, developers can analyze which code is under which block of code and all.

Comment: bro i'm referring to your answer, who the f wants to read it with a horizontal scroll bar

Comment: Ahh, I don't know to use StackOverflow that much. I am really here to learn,help and upgrade.

Comment: Thanks @YashrajJain. Actually I am new user of jsfiddle. I formatted the code. Please check it now. Thanks.

Comment: I cannot see your edited code, I hope it isn't reflected till now. Thus, I have added a reference to solve your issue.

Comment: Thanks @YashrajJain. May be I forgot to save. Now I formatted code. I am using your referenced `ToolTip` in my code. Thanks.